# Magento 2 : How To Extend a Layout File From Third Party Module

Tags: magento2, layout, extensions

I want to extend layout file of magfan_blog extension. I put my custom layout in theme folder, but it doesn't work. I'm guessing if this has anything to do with loading order of Magento2. When I extend third party plugin layouts. my customization will be overwritten by module layout file. If I want to extend third party extension layout. how should I do?

**In source layout file, it works**
[image]
**But in my theme folder, it dons't**
[image]

Comment: can you explain more with code what you have try?

Comment: for exmaple  a layout file form third pard module Magefan_Blog. I want to extend the index list layout in my custom theme folder, but it didn't work

Comment: What code you have try?

Comment: I will perfect my detailed code into the content